# Why is Windows Server 2012 not patchable for meltdown, when Windows Server 2008 R2 is?

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2012, patch-management

Just curious, but does anyone know why Windows Server 2012 R1 server isn't patchable for meltdown/spectre?  Windows 2008 R2 (2009) is patchable, but 2012 (2012) isn't?

What was added in the R2 revisions of 2008 and 2012 that allowed for patching where the R1 version of each can't be patched?

Answer (score 1):

The patch is now [ready](http://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=KB4088877) for Windows Server 2012/2008 (non R2). It was released the 13 March, two day ago.

Small read there too: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4088877/windows-server-2012-update-kb4088877

> Starting in March 2018, Microsoft released security updates to provide
>   mitigations for devices running the following x64-based Windows
>   operating systems. Customers should install latest Windows operating
>   system security updates to take advantage of available protections. We
>   are working to provide protections for other supported Windows
>   versions but do not have a release schedule at this time. Please check
>   back here for updates. For more information, see the related knowledge
>   base article for technical details and the FAQ later in this article.
>
> Product update released   Released    Release date    Release channel KB
>
> **Windows Server 2012 - Security Only Update Windows 8 Embedded Standard
>   Edition - Security Only Update    Released    13-Mar**    WSUS, Catalog   KB4088877
>
> **Windows Server 2012 - Monthly Rollup Windows 8 Embedded Standard
>   Edition - Monthly Rollup  Released    13-Mar**    WU, WSUS, Catalog   KB4088877
>
> **Windows Server 2008 SP2 Released    13-Mar**    WU, WSUS, Catalog   KB4090450

Description: A security issue has been identified in a Microsoft software product that could affect your system. You can help protect your system by installing this update from Microsoft. For a complete listing of the issues that are included in this update, see the associated Microsoft Knowledge Base article. After you install this update, you may have to restart your system. Architecture: AMD64 , X86

Classification: Security Updates

Supported products: **Windows Server 2012**

Supported languages: all